# Apache mod_proxy: forward secure websocket to non-secure

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, mod-proxy

The websocket library I rely on ([PHP-Websockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)) does not yet support secure sockets (`wss`). My website is served over `https` though, so I cannot use insecure `ws` connections.

I'm trying to use [Apache's `mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) to forward the secure request that comes from the browser on to the client.

**Javascript**

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com/_ws_/');
```

**Apache VirtualHost**

```
ProxyPass        "/_ws_/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/"
ProxyPassReverse "/_ws_/" "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/"
# I've also tried "/_ws_/" "ws://example.com:8080/"  Same error below
```

Upon trying to connect, the browser receives a `500 Server Error`. The logs show:

> No protocol handler was valid for the URL /_ws_/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

I've confirmed that if I remove the proxy rules, stop redirecting users to `https` and try to connect to insecure sockets from the browser: `new WebSocket('ws://example.com/')`, things work just fine.

My loaded Apache modules include `mod_ssl.c`, `mod_proxy.c` and `mod_proxy_http.c`

`Apache 2.4`

Comment: I have similar issue with bitnami tomcat stack. Unfortunatly I have no enough skills to setup mod proxy, and I remove apache2 web server at all. But please look into this conversation, may be it will help: https://community.bitnami.com/t/tomcat-8-websockets/39477/3

Comment: @degr Thanks for the link

Comment: What about `mod_proxy_wstunnel` module?

Comment: @gre_gor It took me all night to realize that that's what I was missing. I came back to write up my solution, but if you'd like to (if so include a link to the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) , I'll gladly select your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse proxy WebSockets, you also need to load the [`mod_proxy_wstunnel`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) module.